# exposing roles for user in identity

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have a api projet using dotnet 6.
I use Identity, here are my User and Role classes:

```cs
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int> {
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<int>> Roles { get; } = new List<IdentityUserRole<int>>();        
    }
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int> {
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<int>> Users { get; } = new List<IdentityUserRole<int>>();
    }
```

This leads to the following table:

```cs
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "AspNetUserRoles",
        schema: "ancid",
        columns: table => new
        {
            UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
            RoleId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            //...
        });
```

From here I can navigate from `ApplicationUser` to `IdentityUserRole<int>`. That is I can get the RoleId.
If I want the Role name, I must add navigation properties to `IdentityUserRole<int>`. That leads to:

```cs
    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> {
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; }
        public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; }
    }
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int> {
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Roles { get; } = new List<ApplicationUserRole>();        
    }
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int> {
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> Users { get; } = new List<ApplicationUserRole>();
    }
```

But I get the following migration (of course I edited the `OnModelCreating` method in the context):

```cs
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "Discriminator",
            schema: "ancid",
            table: "AspNetUserRoles",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: "");
    }
```

From here I think, ok, the `IdentityUserRole<int>` is allready mapped in the context, let's start with a fresh migration: delete the migration directory and reapply migration from start and... :

```cs
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "AspNetUserRoles",
        schema: "ancid",
        columns: table => new
        {
            UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
            RoleId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
            Discriminator = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            //...
        });
```

I get a discriminator column when nowhere in my code `IdentityUserRole<int>` is used.

Note that there are no discriminators columns in `AspNetUsers` nor `AspNetRoles` tables.

So what can I do to get navigation properties without a discriminator column ?

Comment: It looks like you changed the model, so after the migration you added a property in the database. You need this navigation property to match, why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @Chen because I do not want to change the database.